# How to send mail to myself without any confirm click?

Tags: android

I writing some application that need to send mail to myself ( from the main gmail account to the main gmail account ) with some text.

I found a way to get access to the gmail and create the mail that i need to send ( adding the target address, adding subject and mail body ) but 
when i sending i need to confirm the sending mail.

I looking for simple way just to add this new mail compose in the self gmail inbox .. without any extra click from the application.

Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Is this app for your own personal use, or are you planning on distributing it? If you are planning on distributing it, how are you planning on forcing people to use Gmail? If it's for your own personal use, there are JavaMail ports for Android floating around that you can use, if you do not mind entering your Gmail password into your app.

Comment: the default account of android is gmail - so i not really force them ... i just sending mail from their default account to their default account ...

Comment: "the default account of android is gmail" -- no, it is not. The default account of Google Play ecosystem devices is a Google account. This does not imply that the user uses Gmail. For example, I do not use Gmail. So, I will ask again: how are you planning on forcing people to use Gmail?

Comment: You're exaggerating a bit. 
I'm not forcing anyone to do anything.
My app sends text to the account and that's it .. It does not matter to me which account or from which account .. The main thing is that the text reaches its destination

Comment: "It does not matter to me which account or from which account" -- according to your question, you do care about which account you are using: you want it to be Gmail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in Android itself for sending email programmatically without user involvement (e.g., via `ACTION_SEND`/`ACTION_SENDTO`). That is because the user may one (or more) of any number of email accounts on the device, and each email app is welcome to handle email in its own fashion.

You are welcome to use JavaMail to send email programmatically without user involvement, as I understand that there are ports of JavaMail that work on Android. However, JavaMail requires that you provide it with all of the email details: SMTP server, account information for sending email through that server, etc. You have no means of getting this information, other than by asking the user to fill it in via your own UI. This has privacy and security concerns, and so many users will not want to do this, or may not know the details (e.g., their SMTP server, as they use a webmail service and never deal with SMTP clients and servers directly).

It is possible that Google has a Gmail Web service API that you could use that offers this feature. However, as I noted in the comments, not everybody uses Gmail, and I don't know that their Gmail API offers this sort of send-to-self capability.